# replace url with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I need to delete a part of a url. Google indexer is detecting duplicate content and I need to redirect the url to the main target.

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?id=123456.0

to main target:

http://www.domain.com/index.php?id=123456
```

I need to redirect the first url to the second url, by removing the `.0` and using mod_rewrite on htaccess .

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(index\.php\?id=[^.]+)\.0\s
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```